# AngularJS, access JSON from another controller/service method

Tags: angularjs, api, service, controllers

So i am using an API. I created a service which access that API, let's say we have a Team Controller, which accesses team info such as team name, date creation and its players. We also have a Player Controller which gives info about a player throught the API we're using. When i open a player's info table i have his team id. How do i access his team name using the team id? I tried running a function in double curly brackets, for example, getTeamName and providing the team id. The browser was reloading the page unlimited times and a lot of packets were sent to me making my page load again and again. Here's a sample code:

controllers.js

```js
    myAppControllers.controller('teamController', function($scope, $routeParams, myAPIservice) {
    $scope.id = $routeParams.id; // Team Id

    myAPIservice.getTeam($scope.id).success(function (response) {
        $scope.team = response;
    });

    myAPIservice.getTeamPlayers($scope.id).success(function (response) {
        $scope.players = response;
    });
});

myAppControllers.controller('playerController', function($scope, $routeParams, mundialAPIservice) {
    $scope.id = $routeParams.id; // Player Id

    myAPIservice.getPlayer($scope.id).success(function (response) {
        $scope.player = response;
    });
});
```

services.js

```js
myAppServices.factory('myAPIservice', function($http) {

  var myAPIservice = {};

    myAPIservice.getTeam = function(team_id) {
      return $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://whatever.com/api/team/' + team_id + '?apikey=fff'
      });
    }
    
    myAPIservice.getTeamPlayers = function(team_id) {
      return $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://whatever.com/api/players?apikey=fff&teamId=' + team_id
      });
    }

    myAPIservice.getPlayer = function(player_id) {
      return $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://whatever.com/api/players/' + player_id + '?apikey=fff'
      });
    }
```

Sorry for any mistake, if i should provide more info on my code say it, i wrote this post on rush.

Answer (score 0):

```
myAppControllers.controller('playerController', function($scope, $routeParams, mundialAPIservice) {
    $scope.id = $routeParams.id; // Player Id

    myAPIservice.getPlayer($scope.id).success(function (response) {
        $scope.player = response;
    });
    //I assume player resoponse contains team id in teamId property .. passing it to getTeam method to get team name
     myAPIservice.getTeam ($scope.player.teamId ).success(function (response) {
        // i am only getting team name but you can other info in response too  
        $scope.player.Teamname = response.Teamname;
    }); 

});
```

This should work imo. Since your service has getTeam and service is already injected . You can access any service method form any controller provided that service is injected .